# How can avoid arithmetic overflow in sql server if I dont have a column destiny?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  client, 
  month1,
  month2,
  month3,
  month4,
  month5,
  month6,
  (isnull(month1, 0) +
   isnull(month2, 0) +
   isnull(month3, 0) +
   isnull(month4, 0) +
   isnull(month5, 0) +
   isnull(month6, 0)) /6 as prom
FROM client_total_sales
```

Months can have null values.

I tried with round, converting data types, but the problem persist.

SQL Server Management Studio show the error during load of the query, I mean a see a few results before the error comes out.

Error message:
Mens. 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Error de desbordamiento aritmético (arithmetic overflow error) al convertir expression al tipo de datos int.

Comment: What are you asking? How to avoid SSMS crash? Have you tried multiple times? How many rows should the result output? What have you read about SSMS crashing by now? In the meantime, look [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/06/25/what-to-do-when-management-studio-hangs), maybe it helps.

Comment: I mean a see a few results before the error comes out.

Comment: client_total_sales is a view right?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: client_total_sales is just the column name

Comment: What is the data type for columns month1 through month6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is `Arithmetic Overflow` in the calculated column `prom`you can force a promotion to a data type that can hold more data by casting one of the parameters of the calculation like this:

```
SELECT 
  client, month1, month2, month3, month4, month5, month6,
  (
   cast(isnull(month1, 0) as bigint) +
   isnull(month2, 0) + isnull(month3, 0) +
   isnull(month4, 0) + isnull(month5, 0) +
   isnull(month6, 0)) /6 as prom
FROM client_total_sales
```

Not knowing what data type monthX is I choose BIGINT for the example. SQL Server doesn't promote to BIGINT automatically so you have to do it yourself.